# How to copy property values to Entity Framework Core object without loosing attached context

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

We would like to have a method which copies all properties of a given input object to an existing entity framework core object which was loaded from the database and therefore is in attached state.

We have tried [Automapper](https://automapper.org/) and [AnyClone](https://www.nuget.org/packages/AnyClone) to copy all properties from the input to the database object. The copy itself works fine but when we then store/save the database object Entity Framework creates a new entry instead of updating the existing one.

Is there some kind of hidden property which we should not copy in order to not loose the attachment to the `DbContext`?

Comment: Can you add the code you see the problem in which? It'll help diagnosing the problem better. It looks like that a property with the role of id/key is getting overridden.

Answer (score 3):

Entity Framework Core has this ability included:

```
db.Entry(current).CurrentValues.SetValues(ord);
```

Taken from [Update Entity Framework object from another object of same type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20741206/update-entity-framework-object-from-another-object-of-same-type)

Comment: Jesus! How can i have missed this one... Works like a boss

Answer (score 0):

I think using NoTracking may help you. Here is a link to some explanation about what is NoTracking.
https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/no-tracking-with-entity-framework-core/