# Updating a record using a class object with Entity Framework in C#

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have an entity class which includes many fields.
To make it simple, let's assume the class is defined as following:

```
public partial class Branches
{

    public int num { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string street { get; set; }
    public string city { get; set; }
```

In my API class, I want to define a function for updating a record of this type.
As creating a function to update each field separately seems like quite an overhead for my application, I decided to define one function that updates all fields.
Can I assign the object received by the function directly to the object used for the update as following?

```
void updateBranch(Branches branch)
{
  using (var dbContext = new entitiesContext())
  {
    var result = dbContext.Branches.SingleOrDefault(b => b.num == branch.num);                                                
    if (result != null)
    {
      **result = branch;**                        
      dbContext.SaveChanges();
    }
  }
}
```

I'm using Entity Framework version 6.0

Comment: "many fields". I'm not sure if you should set the whole entity to `Modified`, see this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/30824229/861716

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can use it, with the following code

```
void updateBranch(Branches branch)
{
    using (var dbContext = new entitiesContext())
    {
        dbContext.Branches.Attach(branch);
        dbContext.Entry(branch).State = EntityState.Modified;              
        dbContext.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

When you attach a Entity to DBContext, Entity Framework is aware that this instance exist in database and will perform an update operation.

Comment: This causes an error saying that the lambda expression is not a delegate type.

Comment: sorry, still not working :(  I see the original record without the modifications

Comment: Try now! without modified EF thought that nothing was changed in the object!