# Linq Update query with Mulitple Tables

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework, linq

I need to convert the following Query to `Linq` :-

```
UPDATE INOUT
SET TIME_FLD1 = A.SCODE,
    TIME_FLD2 = B.STATUS
FROM SHIFTSCHEDULE A,
     SHIFT B,
     INOUT C
WHERE A.COMPANY = B.COMPANY
  AND A.SCODE = B.SCODE
  AND A.CODE = C.CODE
  AND A.SHIFT_DATE = C.DATE1
```

Normally I do Update like this :-

```
    var data = ctx.INOUT.Where(m=>m.COMPANY == COMPANY).Select(m=>m).FirstOrDefault();
    ctx.INOUT.Attach(rec);    
    ctx.Entry(data).State = EntityState.Modified;
    ctx.SaveChanges();
```

Can anybody explain what the Sql query exactly does? And how to do it in `Linq`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suppose this is what you're looking for:

```
        //Select your data
        var data = from A in contextDB.SHIFTSCHEDULE
                    from B in contextDB.SHIFT
                    from C in contextDB.INOUT
                    where   A.COMPANY == B.COMPANY
                            && A.SCODE == B.SCODE 
                            && A.CODE == C.CODE 
                            && A.SHIFT_DATE == C.DATE1
                    select new { A, B, C};

        //interate througt collection and update
        foreach (var row in data)
        {
            row.C.TIME_FLD1 = row.A.SCODE;
            row.C.TIME_FLD2= row.B.STATUS;
        }
        //save changes
        contextDB.SaveChanges();
```

Linq to SQL can't update many records at the same time. That's pitty, but it's true so you should get your collection, and then update entities one by one.

Comment: Is there any need to write this one :- `ctx.INOUT.Attach(row);  ctx.Entry(row).State = EntityState.Modified;`?

Comment: @Anup since you get your entity from `contextBD` it's already attcahed  and you don't need to manipulate  `State` manualy, you need it if you attach entity to DB. A bit more info you can find [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7106211/entity-framework-why-explicitly-set-entity-state-to-modified)

Answer (score -1):

The SQL query is updating from multiple tables, and its LINQ version should be like this:

```
var data = (from A in contextDB.SHIFTSCHEDULE
        from B in contextDB.SHIFT
         from C in contextDB.INOUT
        where A.COMPANY==B.COMPANY
        && A.SCODE==B.SCODE && A.CODE==C.CODE && A.SHIFT_DATE==C.DATE1
        select new {A,B,C}).FirstOrDefault();
if(data != null)
{
  data.TIME_FLD1= data.SCODE,
  data.TIME_FLD2= data.STATUS
 contextDB.SubmitChanges();
 }
```

Comment: `data` don't have `TIME_FLD1` property if we follow your example

Comment: Also `contextDB.SubmitChanges();` is not working in my code. Do you mean `contextDB.SaveChangs()`?

Comment: @Anup This query is in LINQ to SQL that's why I used SubmitChanges, EntityFramework uses SaveChanges instead of SubmitChanges. If you're expecting your answer in EF then please add Entity Framework tag in your question.