# Is it possible to make ad-hoc partial update using EF-Core?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

*I found such post about partial update: [What is the best way to perform partial updates in EF core and never update certain properties?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49922272/what-is-the-best-way-to-perform-partial-updates-in-ef-core-and-never-update-cert)*

My case is the following -- I have a table let's say Person with Id, Name, LastName, DateOfBirth, etc. And a lot of time I need to update all the fields, no problems with that.

But also there are times I need very narrow update, I have Id at hand, nothing else, and I only want to set field LastSeen.

Fetching full record just to change one field is wasteful for me, resorting to raw SQL is possible but looks ugly on the other hand.

Is there a way to stay within EF Core "limits" and perform partial update in given moment?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, starting with EF Core 7, you can use the ExecuteUpdate(Async) and ExecuteDelete(Async) methods:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/saving/execute-insert-update-delete

```
context.Persons
  .Where(p => p.Id == id)
  .ExecuteUpdate(setters => setters.SetProperty(p => p.LastSeen, DateTime.Now));
```

Answer (score 1):

Since EF Core 7 you can use [`ExecuteUpdate`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/saving/execute-insert-update-delete#executeupdate):

```
ctx.Persons
   .Where(p => p.Id == id)
   .ExecuteUpdate(setters => setters.SetProperty(b => b.LastSeen, DateTime.UtcNow));
```

> `ExecuteUpdate` and `ExecuteDelete` are a way to save data to the database without using EF's traditional change tracking and `SaveChanges()` method.

The query will be translated directly to SQL without need to fetch data to the client side.