# Update a data without modifying CreatedBy and CreatedDate while updating the existing record

Tags: c#, .net-core, entity-framework-core, dbcontext

As am updating the data which is already present in database and that table has the columns like **CreatedBy, CreatedDate, ModifiedBy, ModifiedDate**. CreatedBy and CreatedDate is inserted when the new row is created but while updating, I don't need to update CreatedBy and CreatedDate and I need to modify only ModifiedBy and ModifiedDate.

As shown in the below code, it will update the CreatedBy as null and CreatedDate as like 01/01/0001 something like this.

```
_Context.UserProfile.Update(userProfile);
```

and my model is like,

```
public class MyModelUserProfile
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string Username { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string CreatedBy { get; set; }
    public string ModifiedBy { get; set; }
}
```

Is there any way to avoid updating CreatedBy and CreatedDate column? I can do that by getting that particular record by its email id but i don't want to hit the database once again for this.

Comment: *As shown in the below code* -- That doesn't show why these properties/fields should be updated. Depends on how `userProfile` is modified. BTW, where are the date properties?

Comment: Use the answer from the link, but specify `Ignore` rather than `Throw`.

Answer (score 2):

You do not need change `CreatedBy` and `CreatedDate` properties in your model.

Your scenario is here:

1. Read your entity from Database
2. Modify properties which you plan to update
3. Do not modify `CreatedBy` and `CreatedDate`
4. Update your model to Database

Also you model designed not good.
You need to use `DateTime` for dates and `Int32` for numbers.

Please change your model like it:

```
public class MyModelUserProfile
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string Username { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public int CreatedBy { get; set; }
    public int ModifiedBy { get; set; }
    public DateTime ModifiedDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime CreatedDate { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Perfect! My mind will work like dumb sometimes. One more question, Can't I do that by hitting the database only once.

Comment: @ChandanYS See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30824229/861716) for some alternatives.