# EF Core - DbContext.Update vs DbContext.Entry(exitingEntity).CurrentValues.SetValues(entity);

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-core, dbcontext, ef-core-3.1

According to microsoft docs on [disconnected entities](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/saving/disconnected-entities#saving-single-entities), if the entity is not using auto-generated keys, then the application must decide whether the entity should be inserted or updated:

```
public static void InsertOrUpdate(BloggingContext context, Blog blog)
{
    var existingBlog = context.Blogs.Find(blog.BlogId);
    if (existingBlog == null)
    {
        context.Add(blog);
    }
    else
    {
        context.Entry(existingBlog).CurrentValues.SetValues(blog);
    }

    context.SaveChanges();
}
```

Suppose I use this in the else block (instead of the one shown above):

```
    else
    {
        context.Update(blog);
    }
```

Is it advisable? How is `.Update` different from `.Entry(existingBlog).CurrentValues.SetValues(blog)` especially in terms of the complexity? Which will be less costly to call? I can't seem to find information on how the 2 methods are implemented and their complexity.

Comment: We can only give opinions here. It depends much on your own preferences and non-functional requirements. See also: https://stackoverflow.com/a/30824229/861716.

Answer (score 3):

`context.Update` will attempt to begin tracking the entity. Since you used `Find`, the DbContext is already tracking an entity so calling `Update` with the detached entity reference would result in an exception that an entity with that ID is already tracked.

`Update` can be used if you *know* the record both does exist, and that the DbContext is *not* tracking it.

The alternative to satisfy the tracking check without a DB load would be something like this:

```
if (blog.BlogId == 0)  // New row, Identity ID set by DB.
    context.Blogs.Add(blog);
else
{
    var existingBlog = context.Blogs.Local.SingleOrDefault(blog.BlogId);
    if (existingBlog == null)
        context.Update(blog); // Not tracked, so call Update to update and track
    else
        context.Entry(existingBlog).CurrentValues.SetValues(blog); // Tracked, so copy across values.
}
context.SaveChanges();
```