# Update tracked entity on Entity Framework

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, database, entity-framework

I'm having issues updating a tracked entity with Entity Framework. I'm using dotnet 6.
Let's say I have a SnapshotEntity and an UpdateSnapshotDto.
UpdateSnapshotDto it's the one used as 'input', which takes the fields from frontend. I use AutoMapper to convert UpdateSnapshotDto into a SnapshotEntity.
The easiest approach which I tried (and failed) is this one:

```
        var oldSnapshot = await snapshotRepository.GetSingleOrDefaultAsync(e => e.Id == request.snapshot.Id);
        var newSnapshot = mapper.Map<SnapshotEntity>(request.snapshot);

        oldSnapshot = newSnapshot;
        await snapshotRepository.SaveChangesAsync();
```

But of course is not working because when I assign oldSnapshot = newSnapshot it probably lose the tracking.

So I thought that I could instead just Update from what I have in input, like that:

```
        var newSnapshot = mapper.Map<SnapshotEntity>(request.snapshot);
        snapshotRepository.Update(newSnapshot);
```

But this approach wouldn't work for me because there are some stuffs which are saved in the original which I would lose if I brute-update like that (for example, in the DB, the old snapshot has a CreatedDate and columns like that which are not passed inside the UpdateSnapshotDto).

So I thought to read the file, assign the values and update like that:

```
        var oldSnapshot = await snapshotRepository.GetSingleOrDefaultAsync(e => e.Id == request.snapshot.Id);
        var newSnapshot = mapper.Map<SnapshotEntity>(request.snapshot);

        newSnapshot.CreatedDate = oldSnapshot.CreatedDate;
        newSnapshot.CreatedBy = oldSnapshot.CreatedBy;
        snapshotRepository.Update(newSnapshot);
```

But neither this approach will work, because the oldSnapshot is tracked and when I try to do the Update method it says it's already tracked.

I found 2 solutions but would like to not use those:

- First solution is that I assign to oldSnapshot field by field, for example oldSnapshot.Name = newSnapshot.Name etc etc with all the fields, but really I'd avoid that approach, because in case snapshot will increase of properties this logic would not work anymore and need to be fixed;
- Second solution, I use the third attempt I described but reading the entity with AsNoTracking(), and I'd like to avoid to introduce AsNoTracking() logic inside the project.

Any idea? Another solution would be probably use reflection to assign at the old tracked entity all the new ones, but I don't know how to do that and it's probably 'too high level' for a simple update.

Comment: You must copy `request.snapshot` properties to `oldSnapshot`.

Comment: Is it the only option? I mean, do I really have to assign one by one all the properties? Let's say they are 40 properties, there isn't another way? Do I have to do 40 assignments?

Comment: See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30824229/861716) for inspiration.

Comment: `mapper.Map` - is it automapper call?

Comment: Research AutoMapper.Collection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I use AutoMapper to convert UpdateSnapshotDto into a SnapshotEntity.

AutoMapper has ability to map from data to an existing instance, so you can just use it instead of creating a new one:

```
mapper.Map(request.snapshot, oldSnapshot);

// ...

await snapshotRepository.SaveChangesAsync();
```

Also see [AutoMapper.Collection](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper.Collection).